# Probability of rolling any number on a dice exactly twice in 6 rolls

Tags: probability

I am trying to find the probability that when rolling a six sided die 6 times, at least 1 number comes up exactly twice. I know the binomial theorem can be used to find the probability for a specific number, I am interested in any number.

Comment: I would approach via inclusion-exclusion.  Can you find the probability that you get exactly two $1$'s?  How about exactly two $2$'s?  Can you find the probability that you get exactly two $1$'s *and* exactly two $2$'s?  Now, how about the probability that you get exactly two $1$'s, exactly two $2$'s, and exactly two $3$'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inclusion exclusion over the events $A_1,\dots, A_6$ where $A_i$ is the event that the number $i$ was rolled exactly two times.

$Pr(A_1) = \binom{6}{2}\frac{5^4}{6^6}$

$Pr(A_1\cap A_2) = \binom{6}{2,2,2}\frac{4^2}{6^6}$

$Pr(A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3) = \binom{6}{2,2,2}\frac{1}{6^6}$

Recognize it is impossible for four or more events to yield a non-trivial intersection so we can stop there.

Noting the symmetry of the problem and applying inclusion exclusion gives us the final probability as being:

$$6\binom{6}{2}\frac{5^4}{6^6} - \binom{6}{2}\binom{6}{2,2,2}\frac{4^2}{6^6}+\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{2,2,2}\frac{1}{6^6}$$